# How to import base64 in Python

Tags: python, import, base64, tibco

I am writing an Iron Python script in Tibco Spotfire and I need to use the base64 module to encode an image.

The module is not initially integrated in the framework and I also cannot install it.

1. Is there a cloud link or url from which i can import base64?
2. May I upload this module to the cloud myself to import it in script afterwoods? And if yes, what is the easiest way to do this?

P.S. The same quiestion for the PIL (Python Imaging Library)
Thanks!

Comment: base64 is part of the standard library, there is no need to install it.

Comment: yet if I write "import base64", the error is "No module named base64"

Comment: https://community.tibco.com/questions/python-library-available-spotfire-dont-they-provide-all-basic-python-library

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a Tibco issue.

There seems to be multiple community posts though:

1. https://community.tibco.com/questions/python-library-available-spotfire-dont-they-provide-all-basic-python-library
2. https://community.tibco.com/questions/importing-standard-python-modules-issue

It seems that not all modules of the standard library are installed as default, and you do need to add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Download the "base64" tar ball from the internet.
You then need to untar its contents in your user's home or wherever.
Go to the directory created by un-tarring the tar ball. and create the below file so python knows it's a package.

```
touch /your/path/to/package/__init__.py
```

in your script/console:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/your/path/to/")
from package import base64
```